# DateTimeFormat annotiation not working for location time

Tags: java, datetime-format, localtime, datetimeformatter

I am using following to get HH:MM format for time in my pojo:

```
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = HTConstants.TIME_FORMAT)
    private LocalTime checkOutTime;
```

But it returns HH:MM:SS. Any other ways to do this or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `pattern="HH:mm"`?  Make sure you use lower case `mm`, not `MM`.

Comment: Just did, I tried hh:mm and HH:mm both same value is returned.

Comment: OK, then the problem is not in the code that you've shown.  Can you show the code where you're returning it, or showing it as a `String`?